Viber taking focus when new message is recieved
Whenever I receive a message on Viber, it takes focus - maximizes over any app that I'm currently using. If I'm typing something in another app, suddenly Viber pops up and I'm typing in the message box, which is unacceptable. Imagine hitting enter before noticing the app change. I looked around and found this, but I don't know how to apply it to Ubuntu on X11. How can I solve this, either for Viber or any program in general?

Viber 21.8.0 (AppImage)
Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS


Current AppImage Viber version is 23.2.0.3. Upgrade and see if the problem still exists

Unfortunately, I didn't have a chance to test this since I'm not using Ubuntu on my machine due to the many Windows apps required for my studies. If anyone else tested this, posting here would be a good idea. I apologize for the late reply!
